# What does "be" mean here?

Tags: vocabulary

> Every time one of their men was lost, the white pieces showed no
>   mercy. Soon there was a huddle of limp black players slumped along the
>   wall. Twice, Ron only just noticed in time that Harry and Hermione
>   were in danger. He himself darted around the board, taking almost as
>   many white pieces as they had lost black ones. 
>       "**We're nearly there** [= (at) the entrance of next room]," he muttered suddenly. "Let me think let me think..." (Harry Potter and
>   the Sorcerer's Stone)

Does ‘are’ mean 2 or 5 in [OALD](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/be) or something else? : It seems to me 5. If yes, can the phrase be substituted with ‘we nearly arrived there’?

> 2 [intransitive] + adverb/preposition to be located; to be in a place
>
> 5 [INTRANSITIVE] + adverb/preposition to attend an event; to be present in a place

Is there any way I can easily determine things like this for future reference?

Comment: I can't find any meaningful distinction between (2) and (5).  They both condense down to "to be located *somewhere*"- whether that *somewhere* is "at the party", "at the house", "at the concert", "at the end of the road", it's all the same.

Comment: @Jim: The only difference I can see between (2) and (5) is that (5) allows for an _event_ to be named, rather than just a place. So, for example, that allows a speaker to say "We are **at the concert**" (an event) and not merely "We are **in the concert hall**" (a location). To the O.P.: I'd align this with (2) and not (5), although, as Jim mentions, it's really [six in one hand, half dozen in the other](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/six+of+one+and+half+a+dozen+of+the+other).

Comment: @J.R.- I saw that distinction too (which is why my examples covered those equally), but I really don't see any advantage to making the distinction.  Also: This may be more LitCrit, but when Ron said, "We're nearly there" I don't think he meant literally "at the entrance of the next room," I think he meant *we have almost won the chess game and defeated the impediment*, in which case it's not really "a place" it's more like a state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to me, it's 2- to be in a place. We're nearly there. It can't be replaced by- we nearly arrived there. We can at most say- we have nearly reached there.